# Motorcycle: Way to stop plastics fading?

Tags: motorcycle, cosmetic, instrument

I have a 13yo motorcycle that has a black plastic instrument panel. Although it is not regularly exposed to the sun the black plastic is fading to a chalky white.

I was wondering if anyone knew of a treatment or way to prevent this from occurring?

Comment: @Vikas - You've wasted your points on the bounty. We don't do product recommendations on this site.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 in that case it would be unfortunate. Note that in the bounty summary I kept it kind of optional to suggest products ;) (Unfortunately I can't edit it to explain better now)

Comment: @Vikas - If you look at how old the original thread is, I'm pretty sure the shopping questions and product recommendations were taken off the table after that time. Site standing right now is we don't do product recommendations. Also, getting a reply from the Answer OP may be problematic as they are not a regular.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Meguiars and Turtle Wax have both been making all kinds of plastic cleaners and protectants for a long time, and something like [ultimate black](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003814PRM) is probably one of your best bets. Ideally though, you would have been applying some of this stuff to your bike for the last 13 years to prevent fading in the first place. They say an ounce of prevention is worth a pound of cure.

Sometimes though, you just have to replace the plastic on motorcycles if you want it to look new. A little bit of sunshine here and there will take its toll on motorcycles. Even just an hour or so a day multiplied by 13 years starts to add up.

Comment: Hi. I sit only for restoration or you can use it on new bike for protection as well? Like I don't want my bike's black plastic to fade. Can it be used to protect it?

Answer (score 6):

**I've never done any replacement of black plastic on my motorcycles.**

I had a BMW mechanic show me a trick on an early 80's BMW he was restoring.  He sprayed all the plastic with WD-40.  Just saturated it.  He then wrapped all of it in plastic or sealed the smaller pieces in sandwich bags.  A week later we powerwashed all of it and let it dry.

That was three years ago and all of his black plastic looks fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

I'll keep it simple. Use any clear liquid silicone spray. Give the plastic trim a nice heavy spray, let it dry off for 6 to 8 hours and then wipe off the excess with a micro fibre towel. Do this once a month. Not only does it protect you from the sun, it also makes the area water proof. I've been doing this for the past 15 years on our Jeep, Honda's, and Mercedes-Benz sedans.

Just ensure the area is thoroughly water washed and dried off prior to spraying the liquid silicone. If the silicone gets on to any painted surface make sure you wipe that off immediately, except the plastic surface which would require up to 8 hours. Try to do this under a shade and avoid direct sun light until the curing of 6 to 8 hours. For best results, give the plastic trim 3 to 4 coats of silicone spray within 6 hours of each coat. This will create a strong thick transparent film of protection around, and would require a total of 18 to 24 hours in curing.